# Preparing to DLR-Math

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

Here is a question which I could not solve when preparing for my exam.

> A car averages 27 miles per gallon. If gas costs $4.04 per gallon,  which of the following is closest to how much gas would cost for this car to travel 2,727 typical miles?

My closest answer: $109.08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the units to guide your arithmetic.  You are given:

- The mileage of the car, in miles per gallon.
- The price of gasoline, in dollars per gallon.
- The distance to travel, in miles.

You want to know the cost of the journey, in dollars.  Essentially, you want to convert that quantity of miles into a dollar amount.

When multiplying units, you can cancel units that appear in the numerator and denominator.  Like so:
$$
\require{cancel}
(2727\,\cancel{\text{miles}})
\left(\frac{1\,\cancel{\text{gallon}}}{27\,\cancel{\text{miles}}}\right)
\left(\frac{\$4.04}{1\,\cancel{\text{gallon}}}\right)
= \$408.04
$$